# Sources to learn more about Audio/Video compression, codecs, algorithms etc.

Tags: compression

I was quite surprised when [I learned](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2002/apr/04/internetnews.maths) the fact that the MP3 codec is extensively based on the [Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform). I'd like to learn more about these topics in general. When I say more I mean the working principles of these technologies.

For even more clarity, I would prefer something like [this video](http://xiph.org/video/vid1.shtml) produced by Xiph.org

Answer (score 4):

Compression codecs and methods are also based extensively in the field of Psychoacoustics.  For this, I thoroughly recommend the books available from the [Focal Press](http://www.focalpress.com/audio.aspx), such as [this one](http://textbooks.elsevier.com/web/product_details.aspx?isbn=9780240521756&Search=978-0-240-52175-6&SearchCriteria=Keyword)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is interested, Coursera just started a "Fundamentals of Digital Image and Video Processing" in partnership with Northwestern University. From the syllabus, it looks like many relevant topics will be explored.

https://www.coursera.org/course/digital

The course started on March 31, 2014. Here is the general course outline:

- Introduction, Image and Video Processing vs Image and Video
  Analysis vs Computer Vision, the electromagnetic spectrum,
  applications of image and video processing
- 2D and 3D signals and systems, linear and shift invariant systems (convolution) •    2D and 3D Fourier transform, 2D and 3D discrete-Fourier transform, uniform
  sampling (rectangular, arbitrary geometry)
- Motion estimation and
  its applications
- Image and video enhancement (e.g., edge detection,
  noise filtering, histogram equalization, inpainting)
- Image recovery
  (restoration, super-resolution)
- Video recovery (restoration,
  super-resolution)
- Lossless compression
- Image compression
  techniques and standards
- Video compression techniques and standards
- Image and video analysis (e.g., 2D and 3D segmentation, anomaly
  detection, clustering)
- Sparsity-based advances in image and video
  processing

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for a comprehensive resource on video/audio codecs.
Wikipedia article [Comparison of video codecs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_codecs) is a good start.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend Wikipedia. They will have all the information you want, and have links to more information.

Comment: This answer is really general and doesn't really help the OP. Could you maybe edit it to make it more specific? Maybe add links to relevant Wikipedia pages.